# Razor: hidden password control (2 page registration)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm creating a 2-page registration process in razor. The difficulty here is gathering data (username, passwd, etc) on the first page and using hidden input variables to store the first page's data on the second.

here is my hidden code:

```
<div id="hidden vals" style="display:none;">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.userRegisterModel.UserName)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.userRegisterModel.studentFirstName)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.userRegisterModel.studentlastName)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.userRegisterModel.Email)
    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.userRegisterModel.Password)
    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.userRegisterModel.ConfirmPassword)

</div>
```

the challenge is in password and confirmpassword. I don't want to use a hidden field of password type but i want my password persisted but not revealed in page-source. but the "PasswordFor" has a side problem that it "depopulates" the values and makes the user re-populate.

So to re-state, I need my password and confirm persisted and preferably not shown to the user. Moist importantly I need my password and confirm values not hidden from "view source"

My alternative strategy is to use a session variable to store all "page 1 values" but this has other pitfalls id prefer to avoid.

Comment: What about encrypting the password ant storing it in hidden-field, and on submit you may decrypt that password from hidden value.

Comment: yes, encrypting is an option I considered. This is gona come across as lazy, but I have to believe there's an easier way. Though, I agree its an alternative.

Comment: I just believe why to burden on server by creating Session variables, when there is an alternative!

Comment: @Darshan I agree in principle with you and Shyju. I was hoping for a more elegant answer and have objections to both Session objects. On the other hand, as Shyju pointed out, this saves me a lot of trouble while being managable.

Comment: +1 I agree with ur point on sessions. Will probly use anyway but agree with your point.

Comment: Well you should follow the idea which best suit your requirements. No problem with Session variables too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can I suggest a different approach? Instead of two-page, use two-DIV.

You can still leverage things like validation (client & remote) and make sure the user can't advance without a valid form. If there are things that need to be loaded and/or created for the second page, you can do that with Ajax and your form could still live on the page, without the use of the hidden fields or the session variables/timeouts.

```
<form ...>
  <div id="part-one">
    <!-- content... -->
  </div>

  <div id="part-two" style="display:none;">
    <!-- content... -->
  </div>

  <div>
     <button type="button" id="prev-div">Previous</button>
     <button type="button" id="next-div">Next</button>
     <button disabled="disabled" id="next-div">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

The buttons stay visible, you can toggle the state of them with jQuery, and if your requirements change an update to your model class and view are all that is required (if you're using model binding).

Comment: yeah, i really like that approach. It's intuitive and elegant. The knock on this approach is some of this functionality will be re-used. This means using 2 models bound (1 partial) on same screen. Either way +1!

Comment: Not wanting to go around in circles, but if you need reuse, you can move the contents of the inner DIV tags to partial views and it would work that way.  Also, a composite view model, using the pieces that you need, would provide an easy way to pass the model into the partials without having to worry about what you describe.  Thanks for the +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Keep them in Session and access it in the second page / action method.

And ***Make sure to clear that particular Session variable*** once you read from that for persistant storage.

Comment: Shyju, my 2 fall back ideas are Session or encryption. And both are real though not preferable alternatives. In fact the Session approach is growing on me.

Comment: @Dave: I dont see any problems with that approach. this is a temporary storage and you will be fine.

Comment: @Dave : The registration seems to be a step by step process. If the user is taking 20 mnts (Default session time) to come to second page, you probably cal redirect him to the first page again to fill the data.

Comment: Yes, that exact idea occurred to me. And having these thoughts sent back to me I'm leaning more and more toward that idea.

Comment: i just came back to this and realized i never +1d